# Entity Framework: Table-per-Hierarchy on Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

I have set up a view on a legacy table containing order items.  In my program, I want to distinguish between phone orders, wifi orders, internet orders, and miscellaneous orders.  The legacy table doesn't have a discriminator column, however, you can group the orders by their product code string.  Is there a way of creating a table-per-hierarchy from this design?

**Example:**

- *Phone codes:* 30000-01, 30000-02, 30000-05, ...
- *Wifi codes:* 30000-17, 30000-52, ...
- etc.

**Edit:** I still need an order view showing all of these orders for the department listed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a View per type:

```
create view PhoneOrders as
select *
from orders
where code in ('30000-01', '30000-02',...
```

EF should be OK with these, as read-only anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I also need an order view with all the orders on it.  That's why I was thinking of going the table per hierarchy route.  The order view already has a where condition similar to that but with all of the product codes.  Will this solution still work?

Comment: Should do, if I understand what you're asking.

Comment: So I would just have an a PhoneOrder, a WifiOrder, an InternetOrder, and a MiscOrder view, plus an Order view that contains everything in the other views.

Comment: If that;s what you need, yes!